# Gatsby config throw error on new Typescript project creation

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Basically, every time that i create a TYPESCRIPT gatsby project, i get errors on the file gatsby-config.ts.

Errors are in bold font.

```
import type { GatsbyConfig } from "gatsby";

require('dotenv').config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
});

const strapiConfig = {
  apiURL: process.env.STRAPI_API_URL,
  accessToken: process.env.STRAPI_TOKEN,
  collectionTypes: ['article', 'company', 'author'],
  singleTypes: [],
};

const config: GatsbyConfig = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: ``,
    siteUrl: `https://www.yourdomain.tld`
  },
  plugins: ["gatsby-plugin-sass", {
    resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-google-analytics',
    options: {
      "trackingId": "portfolio-vanny-1"
    }
  }, "gatsby-plugin-image", "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet", "gatsby-plugin-mdx", "gatsby-transformer-remark", "gatsby-plugin-sharp", "gatsby-transformer-sharp", {
    resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
    options: {
      "name": "images",
      "path": "./src/images/"
    },
    ***__key: "images"***
  }, {
    resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
    options: {
      "name": "pages",
      "path": "./src/pages/"
    },
    **__key: "pages"**
  },
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-source-strapi`,
    options: strapiConfig,
  }]
};

export default config;
```

[image]

It seems that those errors doesnt affect anything on my project but its weird, i dont even touch the code and it throws me those errors.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: They are not errors. You should configure your IDE accordingly to handle this

Comment: The error says: Type '{ resolve: string; options: { name: string; path: string; }; __key: string; }' is not assignable to type 'PluginRef'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and '__key' does not exist in type 'IPluginRefObject'.ts(2322)